# program is taking input infinitely despite the program scanning one element at a time

Tags: java

I am trying to take input into the variable n. However, it gets infinitelly stuck when trying to take input.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code Here
int i,r=0,max=0;
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
//int i,r=0,max=0;
int n=s.nextInt();
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
   while(i>0)
   {
       r+=i%10;
       i/=10;

   }
  if(max<=r)
    max=r;
    r=0;
}
System.out.print(max);

    }
}
```

I want the program to take one input, then proceed further in the program and compute the result. But, instead it gets stuck while trying to recieve input.

Comment: I can explain why there is an infinite loop, but I don't know how to correct your code, because I don't know what your code is supposed to be doing.  Please add a problem statement to your question.

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger or add `System.out.println()` statements to your code to see what it is doing and to inspect the values of your variables. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for more tips to help you debug your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think the "scanning" in this case was intended to mean scanning in the loop(s).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my code is for finding integer with largest digits sum i.e,from 1 to particular input number i have to find that number whose digit sum is largest for eg.-if my i/p is 32 my o/p should 29 because its sum is the largest

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the inner `while` loop will terminate when `i` becomes zero.  But, the outer `for` loop will happily keep iterating.  So the infinite loop is actually the `for` loop, which will never end.  Without knowing exactly what your code is supposed to be doing, I can suggest that you use another variable instead of `i` directly:

```
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0) {  // use variable j to do the math; don't change loop counter i
        r += j % 10;
        j /= 10;
    }
    if (max <= r) {  // possibly record a new max value
        max = r;
    }
    r = 0;           // always reset r
}
```

Comment: your solution is working but basically i am taking one input and there is no relationship between any loop with the taken input.then what's the fault here and one more thing i can go through 'i' also what is the necessity of introducing 'j' variable..kindly intimate me

Comment: @ravikumarsharma The issue with your current code is that you are corrupting the loop counter `i` inside the `for` loop itself.  In general, with a `for` loop, it is best practice to not muck with the loop counter variable inside the loop.

Comment: how i am corrupting my 'i' variable please elaborate it.i am eager to know this thing

Comment: @ravi Just look at your code.  You are using `i` as the `for` loop counter, but then inside the loop you alter its value, such that after the iteration is complete, it is no longer the original value.  So, the loop continues indefinitely.  All I did, basically, was to use a _copy_ of the loop counter to do the arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `while(i>1)` instead. Using `while(i>0)` doesn't work because you're trying to reach 0 through division, so the loop becomes infinite.